# What SAFE Factory Version is this?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core, recovery

I'm trying to go through this process of deploying my Mainnet Safe address on another chain (Base) for fund recovery: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover

This is the Factory - https://etherscan.io/address/0xC22834581EbC8527d974F8a1c97E1bEA4EF910BC

Can someone tell me what version of the Factory that is? Is it 1.3.0.

Is there something newer?

Should I follow the instructions for 1.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the address of our [Proxy Factory v1.3.0 for Base](https://docs.safe.global/advanced/smart-account-supported-networks/v1.3.0#base), but please use this address only if it the same than the one used to deploy your safe on mainnet. If not it might not be able to deploy your safe at the correct address. If your safe mainnet was deployed using Proxy Factory `0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2`, you should be able to use [this same address on Base](https://basescan.org/address/0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2).

Once your funds have been recovered, you will be able (but you don't have to) to [update](https://docs.safe.global/advanced/cli-reference/common-commands#update-safe) to newer versions for both safes.

Hope it helps; Best, Louis